# HTML H1 - Header Styles Complications

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pseudo-element

[image: This design layout is the objective]

```css
div {
background-color: #ccc;
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
}

div > div {
background-color: #000;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}
h1::before {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  height: 30px;  /*height of icon */
   width: 30px;  /*width of icon */
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   left: 5%;
  margin-top: 30px;
      /*background */
    background: #ffffff no-repeat 0px 0px;
  
}
```

```html
<div><div><h1>Für Designer, Schriftsetzer, Layouter, Grafikenthusiasten und alle anderen</h1><div><div>
```

The example code above is using a  inside another . The actual code uses a layout that is inside another container. So the dot and line elements in the screenshot are outside that container.

The dot is currently displayed with a pseudo-element. I can display the circle but I would like to create the line on the left of it as well. The left-end of the line needs to be stretched to the left edge of the browser.

Thanks

Comment: For your outer `<div>` I would use `<header>`. Then apply the `::after` pseudo-element to the `<header>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by adding an :after pseudo-element to your H1 element and apply some styles to it.

I've created a code example that might help you out. It also centers the dot and line vertically if the header is being displayed with multiple lines:

```css
div {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  div>div {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  h1 {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  h1::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: -5%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: #ffffff no-repeat 0px 0px;
  
  }
  
  h1::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: -105%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
    <div><div><h1>Für Designer, Schriftsetzer, Layouter, Grafikenthusiasten und alle anderen</h1><div><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
background-color: #ccc;
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
}

div > div {
background-color: #000;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}
h1::before {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  height: 30px;  /*height of icon */
   width: 30px;  /*width of icon */
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   left: 5%;
  margin-top: 30px;
      /*background */
    background: #ffffff no-repeat 0px 0px;
  
}

h1::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 6px;
    width: 41px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background: #ffffff no-repeat 0px 0px;
    top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div><div><h1>Für Designer, Schriftsetzer, Layouter, Grafikenthusiasten und alle anderen</h1><div><div>
```

Comment: I have used the following: `.n3-title-container h1::before {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  height: 30px;  /*height of icon */
   width: 30px;  /*width of icon */
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
   position: absolute;
   left: 8%;
  margin-top: 30px;
      /*background */
    background: #ffffff no-repeat 0px 0px;
  
}

.n3-title-container h1::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 8.2%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff no-repeat 0px 0px; top:138px;
  left: 0;
}`